# How to use xsl:number count as condition in xsl:if test "condition"?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Within an xsl:for-each select loop, I have `<xsl:number count="//headline"/>` that correctly gives me the node #; Now I want to use that number in an xsl:if test block, but I cannot get the test expression right, msxml4.dll keeps kicking back errors. Am using xsl 1.0 (and stuck with it for now)

So, in `<xsl:if test="expression">`...output if the expression is true..`</xsl:if>`

I want the test expression to essentially be like this (so I can do something specific for Node #4, in this example):

> `<xsl:number count="//headline"/> = 4`

This is what I have that does not work:

> `<xsl:if test="&lt;xsl:number count=&quot;//headline&quot;/&gt; = 4">`

Thanks in advance for any insights, 
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @michael.hor257k explains, the general approach is to put the xsl:number call inside an xsl:variable (or in XSLT 2.0, inside an xsl:function). Sometimes though it's more convenient to abandon xsl:number:

```
<xsl:if test="count(preceding::headline) = 3">...</xsl:if>
```

If it's a big document then both `xsl:number` and `preceding::headline` are potentially expensive when executed inside a loop, and if this is a concern then you should compare them under your chosen XSLT processor: one may be optimized better than the other.

Come to think of it, your use of `xsl:number` looks odd to me. The count attribute is a pattern, and the pattern `//headline` matches exactly the same nodes as the pattern `headline`. As a result I misread your call on xsl:number as counting all the headlines in the document, whereas it actually only counts the preceding-sibling headlines. I wonder if that is what you intended?

Comment: @michael.hor257k's approach of interim variable works, but your answer is the 1-liner I was looking for. Thank you so much. (Indeed I want to know the preceeding HL count, as I have insertions to place after so many headlines. The headline count is modest (typically less than 40), so this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If (!) I understand correctly, you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="n">
    <xsl:number count="headline"/>  
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
<xsl:if test="$n = 4">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Using your approach of using an interim variable works. Thank you!